# FullScreen Video Bootstrap Resizing Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am having an issue with the resizing of a full screen video, within a bootstrap template.

Here is the live example? http://velnikolic.com/toad/index.php# below 1400px and in safari browsers the video ratio gets very distorted.

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="thumbnail.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">

        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
</div>


/*Video*/

.fullscreen-bg {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: -100;
            height: 600px;

        }

        .fullscreen-bg__video {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 600px;
        }


        @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
      .fullscreen-bg__video {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider **few Website optimization techniques. compress your thumbnails and other media content in order to load faster.** it took me more than a minute for me to load your website.

One more thing i noticed, that is while resizing my browser window, when i switched to mobile view. the video block dissappears. which you can correct by using changing the following code
In your style.css line 450 -

```
    @media (max-width: 767px)
    .fullscreen-bg__video {
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align:baseline;
    }

/*your this css settings are fine*/
 @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
      .fullscreen-bg__video {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }
```

And  I think you just updated the website and the video quality has degraded and when re-sized video is being paused. your last configuration was fine just u had kept **width:600%** somewhere in css.